# Mounting external HDD in Mac OS X from Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, networking, macos, external-hard-drive

I have a 3TB HDD that is connected to my Ubuntu desktop via USB.  How can I mount it (the USB HDD) as a drive on my Mac OS X machine over my network while it's still connected to the Ubuntu machine?

Part of why I'm trying to do this is because I had a previous external 'crap out' on me (OS X suddenly stopped recognizing it; Ubuntu can read it but due to the way OS X partitioned it for `Time Machine` Ubuntu can't write to it).  Is there any formatting I can use so that (ignoring the question above) if I ever wanted to connect it directly to the OS X machine both systems can read and write to it fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want the Ubuntu system to share the 3TB USB drive with your Mac, correct? Then your best bet is to use [`Netatalk`](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net) to setup an AFP compatible share point on your Ubuntu box. The details below are culled from my personal cheatsteet for setup on Ubuntu 12.04; I doubt there are any major differences in other versions since variants of this concept have been used for years on various Linux systems. But I would recommend checking [this site](http://kremalicious.com/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/) as well as [this site](http://computermen.linuxeverywhere.org/2014/01/22/using-a-linux-server-as-timemachine-for-osx-10-7-10-8-and-10-9/) and [this other site](http://www.barryprice.co.uk/2012/05/04/apple-file-server-on-ubuntu-12-dot-04/) for other bits of info.

For starters, install Netatalk using an package installer—such as `aptitude`—like this:

```
sudo aptitude install netatalk
```

If you are using Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or above, then you need to adjust the config. First open it up using whatever your favorite text editing tool is; I prefer `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf
```

Then add this line to the bottom of the file:

```
- -tcp -noddp -uamlist uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2_passwd.so -nosavepassword
```

With that done, you can now add your external USB drive as a volume accessible via AFP by editing the `AppleVolumes.default`:

```
sudo nano /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default
```

And add a line like this to the file:

```
/path/to/usb/external/drive "My Great 3TB Drive" allow:root options:usedots,upriv,noadouble
```

The easy way to parse that line is:

- The first thing is the file path you wish to share.
- The next is the name of that share that will be used.
- Next up is `allow:` which lists who you would like to allow access to the share.
- And finally we have `options:` which might be the place you spend your most time tweaking. The combo I list there works well for my purposes. [Look at this page](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.0/htmldocs/upgrade.html) and search for `options:` to see what options exist.

If you want to constrain access to a group—rather than a specific user—then set the `allow:` to `allow:@groupname` so the line would be something like this:

```
/path/to/usb/external/drive "My Great 3TB Drive" allow:@groupname options:usedots,upriv,noadouble
```

Then just restart the netatalk service like this:

```
sudo service netatalk restart
```

And if you connect to the Ubuntu machine via AFP with an address like this; assuming your Ubuntu address is `10.0.1.2`:

```
afp://10.0.1.2
```

Then you will get a list of available shares. One of them should be `My Great 3TB Drive` as you have setup above. And you should be in business.

But to make your live easier you might want to instal the [Avahi daemon](http://avahi.org) service which is basically an open source implementation of multi-cast broadcasting like Apple’s `Bonjour`:

```
sudo aptitude install avahi-daemon avahi-utils
```

And to setup the AFP service as being accessible via Avahi, edit this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/avahi/services/afpd.service
```

And place this XML into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
<name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
  <service>
    <type>_afpovertcp._tcp</type>
    <port>548</port>
  </service>
  <service>
    <type>_device-info._tcp</type>
    <port>0</port>
    <txt-record>model=Xserve</txt-record>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

Then restart Avahi like this:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
```

And now the shares should be visible in your Mac server list like any other Mac/machine sharing via AFP! The system name shown should be the same as your Ubuntu machine’s `hostname`.

Now, a bonus thing: Look at the XML entry for `model=`:

```
<txt-record>model=Xserve</txt-record>
```

I have that set to utilize an `Xserve` icon as default. But you can basically change that to match whatever system icon you wish to associate to your Ubuntu machine. You can poke around in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist` to see what icons the system has in place to adjust the icon icon to your liking; [hat-tip to Simon Wheatly for this tip](http://simonwheatley.co.uk/2008/04/avahi-finder-icons/). So you can change your `<txt-record>model=[something]</txt-record>` to match items such as:

- Macmini
- iMac G5
- RackMac
- Xserve

And so on.

**EDIT:** Also, your “bonus” question is if there is a way to share an external drive between Mac OS X as Linux without network sharing. Meaning just mounting the drive as a drive on whatever machine you want. Well, it’s my understanding that modern Linux machines can read & write to HFS Plus partitions, but “Journaling” must be disabled. I have not tried this out myself, but experiment with disabling “Journaling” on the drive & see what happens.